# Could anyone help find the problem in this simple c program about averages?

Tags: c

It just gives 0 as average in the end. no matter what values I put in the list. I guess there's some issue in the avg. I am absolute beginner in c. any help would be appreciated.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
    
int main() {
    int sum, list, total;
    float avg;

    printf("Enter total number of values: ");
    scanf("%d", &total);

    for (list = 0; list < total; list++) {
        printf("Enter the values: ");
        scanf("%d", &list);
        list += sum;
    }
    
    avg = (float) sum / (float) total;
    printf("The average of such values shall be: %d", avg);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I would initialize values to 0 to begin with. Also ensure total is not 0 otherwise will crash. You're loop condition doesn't make sense either. list < total?

Comment: You are using `%d` to format a `float`.  Probably will have strange behavior.

Comment: @Eljay Yes, after testing this in an online IDE it prints random values. OP should use `%f` instead. A good compiler would give a warning for this.

Comment: `list += sum` adds `sum` to `list`, while I expect you want the opposite: `sum += list`. Of course, this requires you to explicitly initialize `sum`, as otherwise it will have an indeterminate value and using it will lead to undefined behavior.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int sum = 0;
    int list = 0;
    int total = 0;
    int counter = 0;
    float avg = 0.0;

printf("Enter total number of values: ");
scanf("%d", &total);

for (; counter < total; counter++) {
    printf("Enter the values: ");
    scanf("%d", &list);
    sum += list;
}

avg = (float) sum / (float) total;
printf("The average of such values shall be: %f", avg);

return 0;
}
```

1. Your loop condition did not make sense.
2. Your internal loop was doing list+=sum, sum was never being set or entered in as an input
3. Printing was %d not %f

Comment: Assigning 0 to "sum" is critical, or you could end up with random values. At least that's what happened with the online compiler I used.

Comment: thanks man. I didn't realise I was using %d for printing xd

Answer (score 0):

You're adding sum to list instead of the other way around. So what happens is you're reading a value, storing it into a variable and adding some random value (hopefully 0, since it's not initialized) to it, then overriding that variable with the new value read, and so on and so forth.

```
for (list = 0; list < total; list++) {
    printf("Enter the values: ");
    scanf("%d", &list); // reads and stores value into list
    list += sum;        // list = list + sum
}
```

Try to switch list += sum to sum += list. It should work:

```
for (list = 0; list < total; list++) {
    printf("Enter the values: ");
    scanf("%d", &list); // reads and stores value into list
    list += sum;        // sum = sum + list
}
```

Also, as stated before, get in the habit of always initializing values. Specially counters and accumulators (sum, in this case). Some compilers auto-initialize them to 0 in case no value is specified, but some don't, and you run into the risk of having some random trash value stored into your counter/accumulator.

This happens because the compiler must allocate memory space to the variable, and that memory space can have some random trash values in it. So, as a good practice always initialize.

Comment: understood. thanks for helping